# unzip multiples ficheros a la vez en linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Tengo una carpetas anuales de registros ambientales, que contienen varia información dentro, así:

1. Carpeta principal 2023.zip - compuesta por 142 subcarpetas, así:
2. Subcarpeta (142) Estación1.zip - compuesta por 24 registros, así:
3. Sub-subcarpeta (24) mes1.xml
   mes1.xsd
   mes2.xml
   mes2.xsd etc etc etc.

Usando línea de comando, lo que quiero es tener todos los archivos .xml de cada una de las 142 estaciones en una única carpeta destino, de nombre X.

Usando

```sh
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do 
    find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; 
done
```

Consigo "parcialmente" lo que quiero. Ahora tengo la carpeta

Estación01, compuesta por ficheros .xml y .xsd dentro, y debo quedarme sólo con los xml. Intenté

```bash
find ./ -type f -name "*.xml" -exec cp {} ./ \;
```

pero no hace nada, porque "Estación01" es un directorio y quiero que busque adentro de él. Cómo lo hago? para no ir estación por estación?

Cómo lo debo hacer?

Comment: as intentando hacer un `for file in $(ls /home/u0890cpi/estaciones*.zip) do unzip -jn /home/u0890cpi/$file *.xml -d /home/u0890cpi/X/... done`

Comment: Me funciono esto: while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
Está publicado en https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files
Edito la pregunto y agrego otro problema que me ha surgido